# Proof, the Singular Values of $A+I$ are the singular values of $A+1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to prove if this is correct.

How I tried:

$(A+I)^T * (A+I) = A^T * A + A^T + A + I$

But I don't know how to conclude.

Comment: What's the difference between $A+I$ and $A+1$?

Comment: Being the Singular Values of the Matrix A equals to sigma , the singular values of A+I are equals to sigma + 1 ?

Comment: Ah, ok. So it was "$\sigma$ is a singualr value of $A$ if and only if $\sigma+1$ is a singular value of $A+I$".

Comment: Try $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.